# A point a is a cluster point of a set $A \subset \mathbb R$ iff there exists a sequence ${a ^{(k)}} \subset A\setminus\{a\}$ converging to $a$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

> Prove: a point a is a cluster point of a set $A \subset \mathbb R$ iff there exists a sequence ${a ^{(k)}} \subset A\setminus\{a\}$ converging to $a$.

**My thoughts:**

I know that the definition of a cluster point $a$ of a set $A \subset \mathbb R$  is, for every $\delta > 0$, the n-ball $B_{\delta}(a)$ contains at least one point of A, not counting $a$. but I do not know how to use this definition to prove what required.

Could anyone show me how to prove this please?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: okay I will edit my question I am sorry @5xum

Comment: @5xum: I'm not sure why the change of title.

Comment: It would be good if you include the definition of cluster point you're working with in the question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The original title was so long that, once I edited the latex errors, it was longer than 150 characters. Also, I think this site usually doesn't like questions that are fully stated in the title - the title should be a concise description of what the question is about, not the entire question.

Comment: I have included it @coffeemath

Comment: @5xum: The goal of a title is to tell you what is the question, as best as possible (with the occasional clickbait in some rare occasions). Yes, the question shouldn't be *just* in the title. But there's no problem with a title saying exactly what is the characterization sought for. "How to solve *this* problem" is very nondescript and very annoying compared to "Proving that X is equivalent to Y".

Comment: @AsafKaragila But if the question is longer than 150 characters, then including it in the title is impossible.

Comment: @5xum: I never said "always include the question in the title".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ in the definition of a cluster point to find a sequence. For the other direction, the fact that a sequence in $A \setminus \{a\}$ exists already tells you something about the intersection of open balls with $A$.

Comment: Could you please include some details about the other direction?

Comment: @hopefully  For the other direction, you want to show that every ball with an arbitrary radius $\epsilon>0$ intersects $A$ at a point other than $a$. Right? This means that you should show that $B_r(a) \cap (A\setminus \{a\}) \neq \emptyset$. Now, what does the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ tell you about this? Think about the terms of the sequence $a^{(k)}$. By the way, the notation $a^{(k)}$ to denote a sequence is kind of nonstandard. To avoid confusion, use $\{a_k\}$ to denote a sequence indexed by the dummy variable $k$.

Comment: okay ..... let me please first ask about the forward direction .... I am stucked in finding the sequence if the ball contain a point other than a ... say b... then I will have $ 0 <|| b -a || < \delta$ but then what?

Comment: @hopefully OK. Let's work out the details in the forward direction first. If you take $\epsilon=1/n$ for each $n$, you will find a point $x_n$ such that $0<\|a-x_n\|<\frac{1}{n}$. So, $\{x_n\}$ becomes a sequence that is converging to $a$. Do you agree?

Comment: why are you sure that I will find this point $x_{n}$?

Comment: Why am I sure that I will find $x_n$? Because by definition, given any $\epsilon>0$, the set $B_r(a)\cap (A\setminus \{a\})$ is not empty. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, I'm taking $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$. Then the definition **implies** that some point (let's call it $x_n$) must exist in $B_{1/n}(a)\cap (A\setminus \{a\})$. $x_n$ is just a notation for the point that exists in $B_{1/n}(a)\cap (A\setminus \{a\})$ by the definition of $a$ being a cluster point.

Comment: So now I agreeing with you

Comment: @hopefully Good. Now try to solve the other direction. It's very similar. Let me know if you needed help with it.

Comment: I am now stucked in the other direction .... but I know that the limit will tell me that a is a cluster point but I do not know why ? or more precisely ....how to say this using archemidean property as you mentioned above .... could you help me please?

Comment: @hopefully No, using the Archimedean property is unnecessary here. I edited my answer soon after I wrote it because I realized the Archimedean property was redundant. You're right that the definition of limit tells you that $a$ is a cluster point because given any $\epsilon>0$, you will find $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n \geq N$, the terms $x_n \in B_{\epsilon}(a) \cap (A\setminus \{a\})$. So, $\forall \epsilon>0: B_{\epsilon}(a) \cap (A\setminus \{a\}) \neq \emptyset$ which means that $a$ is a cluster point.

Comment: yes I understood that I will have $0<||a_{n} - a|| < \delta $ which means that the intersection is not empty ..... correct?

Comment: @hopefully Yup. That's correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help.

Comment: @hopefully You're welcome.